# WSO2 - Error while Calling Secured Proxy Service

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm a Beginner in WSO2
I Passed the User name and password for the proxy user and also add the time stamp in the header using SOAP UI

Can someone help to resolve the error I'm facing,

```
[2022-12-20 12:38:25,793] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} - System error org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System error
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:337)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:459)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Hello is not supported here. Envelope can not have elements other than Header and Body.
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:265)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildWithAttachments(OMElementImpl.java:1086)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.setAuthHeaders(POXSecurityHandler.java:371)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:292)
    ... 10 more

[2022-12-20 12:38:25,850] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing POST request for : /services/WebServer_Proxy.WebServer_ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System error
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:337)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:459)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Hello is not supported here. Envelope can not have elements other than Header and Body.
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:265)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildWithAttachments(OMElementImpl.java:1086)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.setAuthHeaders(POXSecurityHandler.java:371)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:292)
 10 more
```

Comment: It seems like the soap request you are sending is not in the correct format. `Hello is not supported here. Envelope can not have elements other than Header and Body`